# Getting hillshade error "GDAL provider: Cannot open GDAL dataset" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hillshade

I am using a DEM and using menu Raster > Terrain analysis > Hillshade. When I type a simple output file name "MyHillshade" and then click "OK", I get a two-part error message that says:

"GDAL provider: Cannot open GDAL dataset MyHillshade.tif: `MyHillshade.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

"Raster layer: Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: MyHillshade.tif"

How can I repair this situation?

Comment: The message error says only that GDAL cannot find MyHillshade.tif in the file system. So, what is the path of your resulting layer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set the full path.  This error seems to occur when you only give gdal the name of the file.

[image]

Comment: I guess that Elevation layer should be set too.