# Reprojecting raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have a couple of images that I have made with the service "maps made easy" but I have a problem. The images are projected with the CRS: "EPSG:4326, WSG 84"

My normal projection is "EPSG: 25833" so the images are slightly off in placement.

How can I reproject the images so they will fit?

I have tried to use this method, but I get an unreadable file back, I don't know what I am doing wrong.
[How to reproject a raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/how-to-reproject-a-raster-in-qgis?newreg=3f382465149f4d248338f240e847238e)

[image: one of my images]

Comment: Some more details on the parameters you handed the tool (`raster -> projection -> transform/reproject` would be useful. Also it would be nice to know, which data type your output has. Further noteworthy: QGIS is able to project data where it "lies", therefore reprojection is usually not needed. The differences most likely occure due to different data sources/sensors.

Comment: the data type of my starting map is TIF, i set the source SRS to: EPSG 4362 and my target SRS to: EPSG 4936.

When i run the prosess (raster -> projection -> transform/reproject) it sais: "Invalid Layer: GDAL providor cannot open GDAL dataset"

I get several files from the proses but i can't read any of them (file types are: TIF, ERS, AUX)

Answer (score 3):

Datum EPSG:4326 differs from EPSG:25833, EPSG:4326 is [World Geodetic System 1984](https://epsg.io/4326) vs EPSG:25833 based on [European Terrestrial Reference System 1989](https://epsg.io/25833).

So, you have to implement geographic transformation first (raster -> projection -> transform/reproject as @Erik mentioned) between EPSG:4326, EPSG:4936:

[image: Warp QGIS]

and after that project to EPSG:25833:

[image]

Comment: Hello Jane,
I have tried to change between EPSG:4326 to EPSG:4936, but i get the same message:  "Invalid Layer: GDAL providor cannot open GDAL dataset". Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Hi @SimonKjærhus! Maybe your path is not full? See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80487/90384

Comment: Hello Jane, This is not the problem, the path is full and have been it the whole time.

Comment: Hmm will you please add your GDAL\OGR console call from Warp window ?

Comment: gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4936 -of ERS "C:/Users/s_mad/Documents/GIS/Opgaver BRK/Wonderfestival/Wonderfestival1.tif" "C:/Users/s_mad/Documents/GIS/Opgaver BRK/Wonderfestival/Wonderfestival1ny061119.tif"

Comment: i think this is what you ask for, but im not sure.

Comment: Yes!This is what I mean. look at EPSG:4936  - Unit: metre, Datum: European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 (https://epsg.io/4936) vs EPSG:4326 - Unit: degree, Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 (https://epsg.io/4326). So, there are different units and datum. (one is geographic and another is projected coordinate system). You can't transform directly from one to another, implement geographic transformation first

Comment: Could you please help me with that, i don't know how i would do that. I thought it was just another "Warp" function.

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Comment: It dosen't work, when i use raster--> Projections-->Warp(reproject) and try to change from EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 to EPSG:4936 - ETRS89 it creates a new layer by the name Reprojected and it's at EPSG:3822.

There must be something more, something i dont understand, because it sounds so simple, but it just dosen't work.

Comment: I have uploadet the map to my Google Drive. maybe its simpler to try it with the file for yourself. 

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U6ffQuLHZgdyP4eYIhy0km3gtfGK7aBN?usp=sharing

Comment: .tif you have uploaded is EPSG:3822 - TWD97 (Taiwan Datum 1997) - Projected, share please your initial EPSG:4326 raster

Comment: Ok, the original files is in the folder now. Thank you for the help :)